# How often do you need to set the configuration file for log4j2?

Tags: java, log4j2, configuration-files

I have several classes within a package and several packages within my project.
For those files that are inherited, within the parent class is

```
 { // File location for log4j2.xml
    System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile",
        "file:\\\\" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Properties\\log4j2.xml");
}
```

And yet, I see `ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.`

So, obviously, once isn't enough.

So what is the general rule that I need to set the system property of `log4j.configurationFile`?

- Once per package?
- Once per class?
- Each parent/base class, regardless of the package?
- Or something else?

What's best practice for multiple classes and packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log4j 2 configures itself on initialisation i.e. whenever a Logger instance is first created within an instance of a JVM, approximately ... the first class in your application which declares a Logger instance causes Log4j 2 to initialise itself. So, the answer to this question ...

> How often do you need to set the configuration file for log4j2?

... is **once**.

The issue reported in your OP: `No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration` is caused by Log4j being unable to find the configuration file you attempted to point it at. This issue is **not** caused by not 'setting the configuration file' often enough.

According to [the docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) Log4j will look for its configuration source as follows:

> 1. Log4j will inspect the "log4j.configurationFile" system property and, if set, will attempt to load the configuration using the
>      ConfigurationFactory that matches the file extension.
> 2. If no system property is set the properties ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.properties in the classpath.
> 3. If no such file is found the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.yaml or log4j2-test.yml in the classpath.
> 4. If no such file is found the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.json or log4j2-test.jsn in the classpath.
> 5. If no such file is found the XML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.xml in the classpath.
> 6. If a test file cannot be located the properties ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.properties on the classpath.
> 7. If a properties file cannot be located the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.yaml or log4j2.yml on the
>      classpath.
> 8. If a YAML file cannot be located the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.json or log4j2.jsn on the classpath.
> 9. If a JSON file cannot be located the XML ConfigurationFactory will try to locate log4j2.xml on the classpath.
> 10. If no configuration file could be located the DefaultConfiguration will be used. This will cause logging output to go to the console.

If your attempt to set `log4j.configurationFile` was successful then option `1` would be engaged but that attempt is not successful, we know this because the error message you quote tells us that Log4j is falling through to option `10`.

I would suggest running your application with -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/path/to/log4j2.xml or ensuring that the `log4j2.xml` is on your application's classpath. The idea of littering your code with `System.setProperty(...)` calls feels like an anti pattern and is likely to be quite brittle since any static Logger which is instanced **before** the `System.setProperty(...)` call will result in Log4j initialising itself before it knows about your config file location.